# Рандомное появление блоков при клике

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Я только в начале изучения js))) Поэтому такой вопрос:
Есть 5 скрытых блоков (display: none) и кнопка с прицепленным к ней событием. Суть вопроса: при нажатии на кнопку включается рандомный счетчик от 0 до 5. И в зависимости от выпавшего числа блоку с соотв. id присваиется стиль display: block. Т.е. он появляется. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии кнопки видимый блок скрывался или появлялся заново, если выпало число, соответствующее его id?
Код html:

```
<div class="container" id="randCont">
      <button id="randing" onclick="rand()">Узнать судьбу</button>
      <div id="one">
        <h1>Первый</h1>
        <p>Первый текст</p>
      </div>
      <div id="two">
        <h1>Второй</h1>
        <p>Второй текст</p>
      </div>
      <div id="three">
        <h1>Третий</h1>
        <p>Третий текст</p>
      </div>
      <div id="four">
        <h1>Четвертый</h1>
        <p>Четвертый текст</p>
      </div>
      <div id="five">
        <h1>Пятый</h1>
        <p>Пятый текст</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Код js:

```
var doc, total, div_R, btn;
doc = document;
div_R = doc.querySelector("#randCont div");
btn = doc.getElementById('randing');

function rand() {


    total = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);

    switch (total) {
        case 1:
            doc.getElementById('one').style.display = 'block';
            break
        case 2:
            doc.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
            break
        case 3:
            doc.getElementById('three').style.display = 'block';
            break
        case 4:
            doc.getElementById('four').style.display = 'block';
            break
        case 5:
            doc.getElementById('five').style.display = 'block';
            break
    };

    doc.getElementById('randing').innerText = "Попробовать ещё";


};
```

Comment: [Как вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661983/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7-1-%D0%B8%D0%B7-10-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83#comment955779_662090), скрипт компактнее получился. Спасибо @Crantisz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пометить все блоки результата некоторым классом, скрыть их по умолчанию, а при нажатии на кнопку добавить другой класс одному из блоков, чтобы показать.

```js
var variants = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.res'));
function rand() {
 var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*variants.length);
 variants.forEach(div => div.classList.remove('visible'));
 variants[index].classList.add('visible');
}
```

```css
.res {display: none;}
.res.visible {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="randCont">
  <button id="randing" onclick="rand()">Узнать судьбу</button>
  <div class="res">
    <h1>Первый</h1>
    <p>Первый текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="res">
    <h1>Второй</h1>
    <p>Второй текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="res">
    <h1>Третий</h1>
    <p>Третий текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="res">
    <h1>Четвертый</h1>
    <p>Четвертый текст</p>
  </div>
  <div  class="res">
    <h1>Пятый</h1>
    <p>Пятый текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

В IE отсутствует метод `Array.from`, поэтому нужно использовать полифиллы либо изменить код на более совместимый:

```js
var variants = document.querySelectorAll('.res');
function rand() {
 var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*variants.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < variants.length; ++i) {
   var div = variants[i];
   if (i === index) {
    div.classList.add('visible');
   } else {
    div.classList.remove('visible');
   }
 }
}
```

```css
.res {display: none;}
.res.visible {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="randCont">
  <button id="randing" onclick="rand()">Узнать судьбу</button>
  <div class="res">
    <h1>Первый</h1>
    <p>Первый текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="res">
    <h1>Второй</h1>
    <p>Второй текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="res">
    <h1>Третий</h1>
    <p>Третий текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="res">
    <h1>Четвертый</h1>
    <p>Четвертый текст</p>
  </div>
  <div  class="res">
    <h1>Пятый</h1>
    <p>Пятый текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает!))) Благодарю!!

Comment: Странно. На локальном работает. Добавил на сайт, пишет: TypeError: variants[index] is undefined . Как быть?

Comment: Проверяйте, как вы считаете index, виден ли variants, и есть ли нужный класс у блоков.

Answer (score 1):

Все блоки должны иметь кроме id, еще и класс - один для всех. И по нажатию на кнопку надо проверять - если блок видимый, то скрывать весь класс (все блоки сразу будут скрыты). А показывать потом один тот (через его id), на который указал перст судьбы)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var doc, total, div_R, btn, da, conts;
doc = document;
conts = doc.querySelectorAll('div > div');
div_R = doc.querySelector("#randCont div");
btn = doc.getElementById('randing');

function rand() {
  
    total = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
    
    conts.forEach(function(item){
    var foo = window.getComputedStyle(item).display;
  if (foo === 'block'){
    item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
    
    switch (total) {
        case 1:
            doc.getElementById('one').style.display = 'block';
            break
        case 2:
            doc.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
            break
        case 3:
            doc.getElementById('three').style.display = 'block';
            break
        case 4:
            doc.getElementById('four').style.display = 'block';
            break
        case 5:
            doc.getElementById('five').style.display = 'block';
            break
    };

    doc.getElementById('randing').innerText = "Попробовать ещё";


};
```

```css
.container div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="randCont">
      <button id="randing" onclick="rand()">Узнать судьбу</button>
      <div id="one">
        <h1>Первый</h1>
        <p>Первый текст</p>
      </div>
      <div id="two">
        <h1>Второй</h1>
        <p>Второй текст</p>
      </div>
      <div id="three">
        <h1>Третий</h1>
        <p>Третий текст</p>
      </div>
      <div id="four">
        <h1>Четвертый</h1>
        <p>Четвертый текст</p>
      </div>
      <div id="five">
        <h1>Пятый</h1>
        <p>Пятый текст</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```