# Как сделать рандомный показ 1 из 10 блоков по клику на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа, блок

Дано 10 блоков:

```
<div id="page0" class="screenpage">1
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="page1" class="screenpage">2
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="screenpage">3
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="page3" class="screenpage">4
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="page4" class="screenpage">5
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="page5" class="screenpage">6
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="page6" class="screenpage">7
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="page7" class="screenpage">8
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="page8" class="screenpage">9
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
<div id="page9" class="screenpage">10
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
```

Нужно по клику на "close" показывать 1 из 10 блоков рандомно.
Имеется такой скрипт:

```
        
            $('.close').click(function(){
                $('.screenpage:visible').hide().next().show();
            });
```

Как прикрутить к нему "Math.random"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените `next()` на:

`siblings()` - все соседние элементы

`eq(n)` - элемент под выбранным номером

```js
$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.screenpage:visible').hide().siblings().eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)).show();
});
```

```css
.screenpage { display: none; }
.show { display: block }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <div id="page0" class="screenpage show">1
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page1" class="screenpage">2
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page2" class="screenpage">3
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page3" class="screenpage">4
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page4" class="screenpage">5
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page5" class="screenpage">6
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page6" class="screenpage">7
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page7" class="screenpage">8
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page8" class="screenpage">9
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page9" class="screenpage">10
    <div class="close">close</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Думаю понятно, что сначала `siblings()` выдает все элементы кроме только-что скрытого, затем с помощью `eq(n)` выбирает из них случайный элемент

Comment: Попробовал, но чёт не работает. Спасибо за идею, буду копать в этом направлении.

Comment: @Gargool да, ошибку пропустил, `random()` - скобки забыл

Comment: выложил код https://jsfiddle.net/Gargool/prjarL72/ - не работает.

Comment: @Gargool  jQuery то подключи https://jsfiddle.net/prjarL72/1/

Comment: заработало, СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: @Gargool не забудьте поставить галочку

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x,y;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  x = document.getElementById('test');
  y = Math.random() * 10 + 1 ;
  x.innerHTML += y + '<br>' + Math.floor(y) + '<br>';
}


$('#FunRand').click(function(){
  
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  var nId = "open" + (n);
  console.log(n);
  console.log(nId);
var mass=["Пусто","Коля","Федя","Толя","Мила","Таня","Женя","Игорь","Вася","Паша","Наташа"];
  console.log(mass[n]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id="test"></div>
   <input type="submit" id="FunRand" value="Получить id " />
```

Comment: Либо , если идентификаторы контейнеров будут какими то другими , типа Маша , Федя , Петя и тд , то собрать идентификаторы в массив , и по Count массива , равного Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1), получать из массива идентификатор блока , который нужно показать или открыть или что то с ним сделать . Нужно только учесть , что Count массива начинается с 0 , и если нужно получать с 1 по 10 элемент , значит в массиве первое значение  - левое должно быть .